# How to build for iPhone 3.0 SDK?

Tags: iphone, deployment, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm pretty new to iPhone. My dev env is setup, XCode has just two profiles: iPhone device 3.1.2 (base sdk) and iphone simulator 3.1.2, either one with release and debug.
I fear I will run into problems now, if I ad hoc deploy to < 3.1.2 phys devices. How can I build for 3.0 base sdk only?

Kind regards

PS: stackoverflow is a great source of knowledge. Most of the Google queries I had during the past 2 weeks did land here :)

Answer (score 2):

Double click your application name under "Groups & Files" then go to the "Build" tab and change the "Base SDK" to "iPhone Device 3.0"

Answer (score 1):

Double click on your project name with icon in xcode. This will open project info of your project.

Select the build tab in it.This will the build and environment related properties of your project.

Go to architecture and set the base sdk as whatever you want.This will change the base sdk.
You should give a check "Configuration" value also that is it set for the profile you want

Hope this helps.